# How do I created a Column of Type Publishing HTML that uses template RichHTMLField?

Tags: publishing, richhtmlfield

When I create a Site Column of Type **Publishing HTML** it becomes a *NoteField*. When I look at a system generated Site Column called Page Content, it is also of type **Publishing HTMl** however it gets created as a *RichHTMLField*.

How do I created a Column of Type Publishing HTML that uses template RichHTMLField?

*NoteField's do not give you the ability to use WYSIWYG editor functionality

Answer (score 2):

Used PowerShell to create my columns the way I wanted.

```
Add-PSSnapIn "Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell"
#Get the site collection and web object
$siteColl = Get-SPSite -Identity "http://sitecollectionURL.com"
$rootWeb = $siteColl.RootWeb

#Assign fieldXMLString variable with field XML for site column
$fieldXMLString = '<Field Type="HTML"
Name="htmlContentLeft"
Description="Publishing HTML column with Template RichHTMLText."
DisplayName="HTML Content Left"
StaticName="htmlContentLeft"
Group="_Custom"
RichText="TRUE" 
RichTextMode="FullHtml"
UnlimitedLengthInDocumentLibrary ="TRUE" 
Hidden="FALSE"
Required="FALSE"
Sealed="FALSE"
ShowInDisplayForm="TRUE"
ShowInEditForm="TRUE"
ShowInListSettings="TRUE"
ShowInNewForm="TRUE"></Field>'
#See field XML on console
write-host $fieldXMLString
#Create site column from XML string
$rootWeb.Fields.AddFieldAsXml($fieldXMLString) 

$siteColl.Dispose()
```

Comment: I think though it would have just been making sure the publishing features were active, then a HTML column with constraints for publishing column would become available.